# Register cell reuse identifier within XCode Playgrounds

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, reuseidentifier

Trying to play with Table in the XCode Playgrounds to understand how it works, because there a lot of stuff connected to the `UITableView` and a few tutorials describe these relations and inheritance under the scenes (like `UIView` -> `UIScrollView` -> `UITableView` -> `UITableViewCell`) and how it manages that inheritance, connections and delegations. Normally with an ordinary tutor, you're given with snippet of code and the instructions how to establish delegate connections in XCode and the right methods to call. Result - you memorize the steps but still don't understand the mechanism of the Table. Below is code snippet that I try to adopt for XCode Playgrounds to draw a simple table. The problem - I can't properly register programmatically reuse identifier for Table cell nether from class or outside it. The nature of error

> reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'.

Please, help and point out what is wrong and why.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let tableData = ["Matthew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"]

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
//Did this part as comments to try to do this outside the class   
//        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
//        self.tableView = UITableView(frame:self.view.frame)
//        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

}

}
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
let tableView = UITableView(frame: frame, style: .plain)
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = TableViewController()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a UIViewController contaning a UITableView, programmatically registering of Custom UITableViewCell Subclasses to an instance of UITableView is implemented by: 
`- (void)registerClass:(nullable Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

This is registeringClass *should* be done before setting up table's `dataSource`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! That's works in that way too. But why the code works right when I omit of setting up table's `dataSource`. The `UITableViewController` use self as table `dataSource` by default?

Comment: Yes, when you subclass a `UITableViewController`, it performs(for free) setting up of the data & (tap)delegate handlers to `self`, the instance of `UITableViewController`.

Comment: For Swift 3, the syntax is: `tableView.register(MyCustomTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`. This is to be written inside the `UITableViewController` in `loadView()` or `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 1):

After long time playing with different solutions of building tables from various tutorials I finally have caught some difference in use between a `UITableViewController` and a `UIViewController` for displaying a `UITableView`. In my example from my question, some lines of code are just redundant. That's happened because I tried to implement the approach of building a table within the `UIViewController`, but I used the `UITableViewController` instead and additionally tried to set the dataSource and all view properties, but as I understand now - the `UITableViewController` already does all this stuff for me (correct me here if I wrong). The functioning snippet of code is below:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

let tableData = ["Matthew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"]

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
    }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
    }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    } 
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = TableViewController()
```